# Renaming several rows in one Columne with specific length

Tags: r

I have a data set with a column "breeds". There are currently 177 different breeds and I need to reduce them down to 53 so I can create a random forest. I'd like to take the ones that are small (e.g.: We have only one Afghan) and rename them to "other".

I tried with "ifelse" statements combined with length(unique())

Comment: small means do you have a threshold?

Comment: I'd have to see from where on I'd be below the 53 categories. They range from categories containing 13'000 samples right down to some where I have only a single breed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, though maybe some of these could be combined:

```
dummy_DT <- data.table("Breed" = c(paste("Breed", round(rnorm(1:1000, 500, 100)), sep="")), "Count" = 1)

agg_DT <- aggregate(Count ~ Breed, data=dummy_DT, length)
sorted_DT <- agg_DT[order(-agg_DT$Count),]
pre_Other <- sorted_DT[53:nrow(sorted_DT),]
final_Other <- sorted_DT$Breed[sorted_DT$Count <= max(pre_Other$Count)]
dummy_DT$Cat53 <- ifelse(dummy_DT$Breed %in% final_Other, "Other", dummy_DT$Breed)
```

It's just taking the number of rows for each breed, sorting largest to smallest, lumping together everything smaller than the 52nd group (keeping all with the same count in the same group, so <= 53 groups total), and labeling those "Other."

```
> length(unique(dummy_DT$Cat53))
[1] 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done it manually now. First made a pie plot an then chose 1/8 of the observations which would become "other".

cats_and_dogs <- transform(cats_and_dogs, newColumn = (ifelse(cats_and_dogs$breed %in%c("Domestic","Pit","Labrador","Chihuahua","German","Australian","Miniature","Dachshund","Siamese","American","Border","Boxer","Jack","Siberian","Great","Yorkshire","Catahoula","Rat","Beagle"),as.character(cats_and_dogs$breed),"other")))

PS: Rat is actually the first word of a dog breed (: